# ASP .NET Core Respository Id Article passed in was changed to 0?

Tags: asp.net, model-view-controller, asp.net-core-mvc, repository-pattern, edit

**I am wanting to Edit Article in the database with ASP .Net Core with Repositoy, everything is fine, but when I enter and press edit, the Article ID will change to 0, below is the code**

**View**

```
    @model Megatron.ViewModels.ArticleFacultyViewModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit Article";
}

    <div>
        <form asp-action="EditArticle">
            <partial name="_StatusMessage" model="@ViewData["Message"]" />
            <div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <label asp-for="Article.Title" class="col-form-label"></label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-5">
                        <input asp-for="Article.Title" class="form-control" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <div class="col-2">
                        <label class="col-form-label">Type of contribution</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-3">
                        <button hidden class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ImportFileCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ImportFileCollapse">
                        </button>
                        <button hidden class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#TextAreaCollapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="TextAreaCollapse">
                        </button>
                        <button id="button-collapse" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".multi-collapse" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="ImportFileCollapse TextAreaCollapse">
                            Switch to Editor
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you are not binding the `Id` of the article when you submit the form in your html. So, the `EditArticle` post action receives no Id, and subsequently shows a zero.